OkHttpClient no class defined when initlialized
So this is the error I've been getting: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/OkHttpClient. I don't really see the issue so I hope to find some helpful advice here.
I tried making a simple http request and excpected to get the response json-parsed and later work with it.
I am using InteliJ IDEA Ultimate, haven't tried out any other IDEs jet.
Related imports:
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

Code snippet:
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(String.format("http://localhost/products/%s/check?v=%s", PRODUCT_HASH, VERSION))
    .build();

try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        assert response.body() != null;
        String responseData = response.body().string();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(responseData, JsonObject.class);
        getLogger().info(jsonObject.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    getLogger().severe("Failed to check version:" + e.toString());
}

Maven dependency:
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
   <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
   <version>4.12.0</version>
</dependency>


Have you tried asking your IDE to reload your dependencies? If you're using IntelliJ IDEA, go to your pom.xml > right click anywhere in the file > Maven > Reload project. Your code works for me

@dani-vta Did that, issue persists.

@MartinZeitler The issue isn't ther but why shouldn't it work?

If you're using IDEA, go to File > Invalidate Caches... > select all > Invalidate and restart. Then, try to reload your dependencies again.

I can't come up with something else, but I'll keep thinking. Can you provide in your question what IDE you're having troubles with and if you're experiencing the same issue on another IDE.

@dani-vta I don't think that this is relevant however this snippet is part of a code functioning as a minecraft plugin (paper-1.20.6)

Considering that the code above does compile, it seems like an IDE or a configuration issue

It is always better to provide a reproducible example, but to start off with you shall look into any mismatches possible between compile and run time.

@IkonoDim Was wrong, thought it was Android, where this wouldn't work.
